# About the Example For Union of Algebraic Sets maynot be Algebraic Set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I just want you to check my example is true or not.

I considered $\mathbb Z$ and I look at single points. We know that single points $ a_i$ are algebraic because they are zero set of $\{x-a_i\}$. But $\mathbb Z$ is not algebraic since the zero set of polynomials are finite. Moreover, unions of singletons are equal to $\mathbb Z$ hence union is not algebraic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can go further: *any* subset is a union of singletons, so if unions of algebraic were algebraic, any subset would be algebraic.

Comment: what about 0? 0 polynomial vanishes everywhere

Comment: Yes, that shows that the whole space is algebraic. But not all subsets are the whole space! Anyway, your proof is correct, you show that if unions of algebraic sets were algebraic, that would lead to a contradiction. I'm just pointing out that the proof is much more flexible than that.

Comment: I notice something now. If I working with $\mathbb C$ which is algebraically closed and take $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb C$ then $V(0)= \mathbb C$. So, I guess for $\mathbb Z$,only choice to being vanishing set of polynomials is infinite product i.e $ ...(x-1)x(x-1)...$ which is not polynomial since its degree is infinite. Could you correct me?